# Middleware for filtering asp.net core REST methods

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have a .net core application with several REST operations (see code below), similar to the following:

```
    namespace Controllers
    {
      [Route("system")]
      public class SystemController : Controller
      {
        // This is a public access method
        [HttpGet("dictionaries/{name}")]
        public List GetDictionary(HttpRequestMessage requestMsg, string name)
        {
          // etc
        }

        // This function shall be accessible only by an admin role
        [AdminRole]
        [HttpPost("dictionaries/{name}")]
        public IActionResult PostDictionary(HttpRequestMessage requestMsg, string name)
        {
          // etc
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to flag some operations to be accessible only by certain roles (i.e. admin). An elegant way to do it is using attributes.

Now I want to determine what would be the correct `Middleware` implementation for **trapping the C# method to be invoked according to the URL**, and fetch the role attribute (if any) by using reflection, so I can block unauthorized calls.

Please advice.

Comment: Isn't the attribute already doing what you want, as in `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]`? Check [the docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/roles.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I want to draw attention that approach below is only if you for some reason does not want to use build-in [Role based Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/roles.html) (as marked in comment to question).

---

If you create a global [Action Filter](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html) (that is a part of MVC and so can operate with "controller logic"), you can get all needed information from  `ActionExecutingContext`:

```
public class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //Provides information about an action method, such as its name, controller, parameters, attributes, and filters.
        var actionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor;

        //Gets the controller instance containing the action.
        var controller = context.Controller; 

        // Gets the arguments to pass when invoking the action. Keys are parameter names.
        var actionArgs = context.ActionArguments; 
    }

    ...
}
```

`context.ActionDescriptor` can be casted to [ControllerActionDescriptor](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/ControllerActionDescriptor.cs). That allows to directly use the following properties:

```
public class ControllerActionDescriptor : ActionDescriptor
{
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    public virtual string ActionName { get; set; }

    public MethodInfo MethodInfo { get; set; }

    public TypeInfo ControllerTypeInfo { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

---

Not sure that you can use middleware for that, as controllers is part of MVC middleware. If you place your middleware before it, there is no "controller" logic at that pipeline step yet. And if after - it is too late for what you want.